# Is there a way to detect if user is not active for a while on Mac?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am developing a Mac application to monitor user's behavior for research purpose. I want to detect if the user is actively using the computer or the computer is just standing by.

Is there an existing method to detect whether the user is active?

Comment: Observe the idle time with ioreg -c IOHIDSystem (shell)

Comment: First you need to very clearly define this. All you can technically know are what events occur. Are saying keyboard and mouse events? What about audio input? Peripheral connection ? Is reading text, watching video or listening to audio an idle event? How about camera input and computer vision as input events? Motion sensors/gyros? Ambient light sensors?